# Why does the value of Semaphore does not change globaly

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

This is my current code, the main issue is I use Semphore to control the output of two process, but it seems like the Semphore does not change globaly, i.e. when process "producer" change the Semphore to 2 the process "consumer" still think the Semphore is zero , which cause it to wait forever.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Semaphore, Queue
import time
from random import random

buffer = Queue(10)
empty = Semaphore(2)
full = Semaphore(0)

class Consumer(Process):

    def run(self):
        global buffer, empty, full
        while True:
            time.sleep(4)
            print(full)
            full.acquire()
            buffer.get()
            print('Consumer get')
            time.sleep(1)
            empty.release()


class Producer(Process):

    def run(self):
        global buffer, empty, full
        while True:
            empty.acquire()
            print ('Producer put ')
            time.sleep(1)
            full.release()
            buffer.put(1)
            print(full)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Producer()
    c = Consumer()
    p.daemon = c.daemon = True
    p.start()
    c.start()
    p.join()
    c.join()
    print ('Ended!')
```

and the output is

```
Producer put
<Semaphore(value=1)>
Producer put
<Semaphore(value=2)>
<Semaphore(value=0)>
```

I don't know what should I do to let "consumer" process detect the change.

Comment: Pass it to the Processes: `Process(args=(empty,))'. As you don't use a Worker Function you have to access the args using `self._args`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two processes have both their own copy of both the semaphores, because each process runs the whole code in the script when it is instantiated.

You must move the semaphores and queue definitions inside the `if __name__ == '__main__':` and pass the instances of the semaphores to the `Producer` and `Consumer` constructors so that they **both** use the same instance of the three objects.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Semaphore, Lock, Queue
import time
from random import random

class Consumer(Process):
    def __init__(self, empty, full, buffer):
      super(Consumer, self).__init__()
      self.empty = empty
      self.full = full
      self.buffer = buffer

    def run(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(4)
            print("Consumer: {}".format(self.full), flush=True)
            print("Consumer: buf {}".format(self.buffer.qsize()), flush=True)
            self.full.acquire()
            self.buffer.get()
            print('Consumer get', flush=True)
            time.sleep(1)
            self.empty.release()


class Producer(Process):
    def __init__(self, empty, full, buffer):
      super(Process, self).__init__()
      self.empty = empty
      self.full = full
      self.buffer = buffer

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.empty.acquire()
            print ('Producer put ', flush=True)
            self.buffer.put('a') #<<<<<<<<<<< you forgot this in your code. If the queue is empty, get() will block on the consumer
            time.sleep(1)
            self.full.release()
            print(self.full, flush=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    buffer = Queue(10)
    empty = Semaphore(2)
    full = Semaphore(0)

    p = Producer(empty, full, buffer)
    c = Consumer(empty, full, buffer)
    p.daemon = c.daemon = True
    p.start()
    c.start()
    p.join()
    c.join()
    print ('Ended!')
```

Comment: GPhilo Thank you for your quick response, I followed your instructions earlier and has come up the code by myself as well, cheers! There is one mistake in your code tho, it should be `print(self.full, flush=True)` at the end of the producer process. Anyway thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Thanks for catching the typo! I updated the answer :)